# How to get full tweets from tweepy?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, api, csv, twitter

I am extracting tweets based on hashtags from Twitter using Tweepy. The problem is the extracted tweets do not come in full length.

Here is my code

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
####input your credentials here
consumer_key = 'XXXXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXXXX'
access_token = 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('new-dataset12.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#PregnantElephant", tweet_mode='extended', count=10000, lang="en", since="2020-04-03").items():
  print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
  csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

When I don't use `tweet_mode='extended'`, it does not give full tweets. And using `tweet_mode='extended'`, it gives the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-50f1dd34d7fa> in <module>()
     24 csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
     25 for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#PregnantElephant", tweet_mode='extended', count=10000, lang="en", since="2020-04-03").items():
---> 26   print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
     27   csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])

AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Can someone please help to figure this problem out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `extended`, you need to get the text by `print(status.full_text)`

do that :

```
try:
    print(status.retweeted_status.full_text)
except AttributeError:  # Not a Retweet
    print(status.full_text)
```

Comment: Should I replace this code with the code inside my for loop? In that case it's not working. Error is - status is not defined

Comment: Replace status by "tweet"

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I've marked the answer as correct. Please upvote the question as well :)